# Display all the names of the employees whose names having letter A as 2nd occurrence without using like operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

For the above query, I am using regexp_count but in SQL command line I am getting regexp_count :invaild identifier;

```
select * from table_name WHERE (REGEXP_COUNT(column_name, 'A')) >2;
```

Is this query works?

Comment: Please at least add sample data to your question.

Comment: if iam having list of employees.......1.saritha, 
  2.mamatha   3.vaisnavi    4.sai,   5.vijaya,    6.kumar.....if i use the above query i should get employee names in which letter A occurence is twice.......like o/p:1.saritha    3.vaishnavi    5.vijaya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want; is it to return names whose 2nd letter is "a", or names that have two or more letters "a" within.

Anyway, pick the one you find appropriate.

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    (select 'saritha' col  from dual union all
  3     select 'mamatha'      from dual union all
  4     select 'vaisnavi'     from dual union all
  5     select 'sai'          from dual union all
  6     select 'vijaya'       from dual union all
  7     select 'kumar'        from dual
  8    );

Table created.
```

**2 or more letters "a"**:

```
SQL> select col
  2  from test
  3  where regexp_count(col, 'a') >= 2;

COL
--------
saritha
mamatha
vaisnavi
vijaya
```

**2nd letter is "a"**:

```
SQL> select col
  2  from test
  3  where substr(col, 2, 1) = 'a';

COL
--------
saritha
mamatha
vaisnavi
sai

SQL>
```

---

On Oracle 10g, which doesn't support `REGEXP_COUNT` function, one option is to replace all letters `a` with an empty string (basically, you'd remove all letters `a`) and fetch rows whose difference of full column length and "replaced" column length is `>= 2`. Something like this:

```
SQL> select col
  2  from test
  3  where length(col) - length(replace(col, 'a', '')) >= 2;

COL
--------
saritha
mamatha
vaisnavi
vijaya

SQL>
```

Comment: @littlefoot....TQ for da reply but if iam using regexp in oracle 10g iam getting error like invalid identifier .......y?????

Comment: Because 10g's regular expressions library doesn't have REGEXP_COUNT function. Does it mean that you actually need to find strings that contain 2 or more letters "a"?

Comment: yep.........strings which contains 2 letters of "A" without using LIKE operator

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more info. Have a look.

Comment: tq @littlefoot i got the answer